# Swift: Why it's a nil NSData when the image file exists in Assets?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata

I use Gifu to display animated Gif. But there's no image showing on my simulator. I inspect that its source code `let imagePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("loading.gif")` returns `file:///Users/Aario/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/25C4D6CF-2482-40GA-4A6E-9493A918DDBC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D1F6DE41-0EB8-43A6-B4DC-70AA524E9620/test.app/default.jpeg` and `let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imagePath)` returns `nil`

So I try to get the NSData from some other images. The default.jpeg exits in Assets directory.
It works well with `named:`

```
let imgView = UIImageView(UIImage(named: "default"))
view.addSubview(imgView)
```

But why I can't convert it into its proper NSData by follow code?

```
let imgPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("default.jpeg")
let imgData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgPath)
print(imgPath)  // print  file:///Users/Aario/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/25C4D6CF-2482-40GA-4A6E-9493A918DDBC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D1F6DE41-0EB8-43A6-B4DC-70AA524E9620/test.app/default.jpeg
print(imgData)  // print nil
let imgView = UIImageView(UIImage(data: imgData))
view.addSubview(imgView)
```

**Error Message:**
    *fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*

Comment: Can you double check your `imgPath`? And also try to move your image to some other folders, such as `Resources`. (Don't put it in the `xcassets` folder.) And then use `NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("default", withExtension: "jpeg")` to get the path.

Comment: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("default", withExtension: "jpeg")   returns nil after dragging this image into directory Resources which I create.

Comment: Did you add it to your target? Check the bundle resources within _Build Phase_.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [PPSwiftGifs](https://github.com/peterprokop/PPSwiftGifs) library for Swift:

- Add PPSwiftGifs.swift & ImageIO.framework to your project.

And assign like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var ImageVw: UIImageView!
ImageVw.image = PPSwiftGifs.animatedImageWithGIFNamed("imageName")
```

Comment: did you added ImageIO.framework to your project as I am using this in my project which is compatible with swift 2.2

Comment: there're abundant of errors displayed in my xcode... Maybe you should try testing with xcode 7.3

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any third party libraries then export all the images from your GIF image and give them a name from 1 to its screen count and add all images into your project then you can show that images into imageView this way:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var loadingImage: UIImageView!

    var imageArray = [UIImage]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for var i = 1; i < 16; i++ {

            imageArray.append(UIImage(named: "\(i)")!)
        }

        loadingImage.animationImages = imageArray
        loadingImage.animationDuration = 1
        loadingImage.animationRepeatCount = 0
        loadingImage.startAnimating()
    }
}
```

Project [sample](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=01547875181604127592) for more Info.

Comment: a nice idea.  I'm learning it. Of cause it's better to use third-party lib

Comment: I tried, it seems like Swift Gif is not support Swift 2.2  Or my git clone has network error.

Comment: do you know what wrong with my importing step as above?